# Python деление не работает

Tags: python

Недавно начал изучать python столкнулся с такой проблемой при делении:

`print(0.0543/666.666)` возвращает `8.145008145008145e-05`,
хотя должен возвращать `0.00008145`

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Comment: `print(f'{0.0543/666.666:.8f}')`

Answer (score 1):

Это все то же число, как верно отметили в комментариях. Это экспоненциальная запись. Если кратко, то
`<число1>e<число2> = <число1> * 10^<число2>`, где

`<число1>` - вещественное число в диапазоне (1, 10),
`<число2>` = целое число != 0.